# How to draw an arrow between this figure?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows, tikz-pic

I have used the `\tikzset{pics ...` environment to define a tikz image so that I can repeat and change just a few arguments. However, I would like to have an arrow that connects the two images. I am struggling to do this since I am unsure as to how to make two distinct nodes for each of the images from which the arrow may join.

I have the following [image](https://ibb.co/erHP8a) which is created by the MWE below. How can I draw an arrow between the two lines at the top with a label that reads $\theta$.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,backgrounds,fit,decorations.pathreplacing,chains,snakes,positioning}  
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,bm}

\tikzset{
pics/gridd/.style n args={2}{
code = {%
    \def \s{0.5}
    \def \nx{3}
    \def \ny{2}
    \def \dx{3}
    \def \dy{3}
    \def \meshthickness{0.01}
    \pgfmathsetmacro \maxposx {\dx*(\nx-1)/2}   
    \pgfmathsetmacro \maxposy {\dy*(\ny-1)/2}

    \draw[line width = 0.2mm] (0, \maxposy) -- (0, \maxposy + 0.8);

    \filldraw[black] circle (2pt); 

    \draw [dashed, line width = 0.2mm] (-\maxposx,\maxposy) -- (\maxposx,\maxposy);
    \draw [dashed, line width = 0.2mm] (\maxposx,\maxposy) -- (\maxposx,-\maxposy);
    \draw [dashed, line width = 0.2mm] (-\maxposx,-\maxposy) -- (\maxposx,-\maxposy);
    \draw [dashed, line width = 0.2mm] (-\maxposx,-\maxposy) -- (-\maxposx,\maxposy);
    \draw [dashed, line width = 0.2mm] (0,-\maxposy) -- (0,\maxposy);

    \foreach \i in {1,...,\nx}{
        \foreach \j in {1,...,\ny}{
            \pgfmathsetmacro \x {(\i - (\nx + 1)/2)*\dx}        
            \pgfmathsetmacro \y {(\j - (\ny + 1)/2)*\dy}
            \filldraw[#1, draw=black, line width = 0.2mm] (\x,\y) circle (#2);
        }
    }
}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\pic {gridd={fill=blue!20!white}{3mm}};

\begin{scope}[rotate around z=20]
\pic {gridd={fill=red!80!white}{3mm}};
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a node/coordinate named `bar` in the `pic`, and the `pic` itself is named `foo`, then you can refer to that node as `foobar` (name of `pic` plus name of node).

Because the rotation  is around the center of the `pic`, it's probably a bit easier to highlight the angle between the vertical lines, as you can just load the `angles` and `quotes` libraries, and then use the predefined `angle` `pic`.

Some more explanations:

The additions I made to the code are not extensive. In the `pic` itself, I added a coordinate at the center, and at each of the vertices:

```
\filldraw[black] circle (2pt) coordinate (-c);
```

Here the `coordinate (-c)` is new, and similarly in the loop,

```
\filldraw[#1, draw=black, line width = 0.2mm] (\x,\y) circle (#2) coordinate (-\i-\j);
```

`coordinate (-\i-\j)` is new. So for example the bottom left corner has a coordinate named `(-1-1)`, internally in the `pic`.

When using the `pic`, I gave them names, `a` and `b`:

```
\pic (a) {gridd={fill=blue!20!white}{3mm}};
```

Because of how `pic`s work, that means that the coordinate in the bottom left corner of this `pic` is named `a-1-1`.

(This is mentioned in chapter 18 of the TikZ manual, where `pic`s are described.)

---

To draw the angle itself, I loaded the `angles` and `quotes` libraries. The first of these defines a `pic` precisely for drawing such angles. It is used as `pic {angle=<coord 1>--<coord 2>--<coord 3>}`. You need three named coordinates, and this `pic` draws the angle between them. It is described in chapter 39 of the TikZ manual (look in the table of contents under the *Libraries* part).

So what I used was

```
\pic ["$\theta$",angle radius=1cm,draw,-stealth] {angle={a-2-2--a-c--b-2-2}};
```

You see that `a-2-2` is the middle, top vertex of the `a` `pic`, `a-c` is the center point of the `a` `pic`, and `b-2-2` is the top middle of the `b` `pic`.

The use of `"<text>"` is a shorthand made possible by the `quotes` library, for adding labels to a path. (This library is described in section 17.10.4 *The quotes syntax*  of the manual.) `angle radius` is self explanatory I suppose, and the last part is to specify that the path should be draw, with an arrow tip.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,backgrounds,fit,decorations.pathreplacing,chains,snakes,positioning,angles,quotes}  
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,bm}

\tikzset{
pics/gridd/.style n args={2}{
code = {%
    \def \s{0.5}
    \def \nx{3}
    \def \ny{2}
    \def \dx{3}
    \def \dy{3}
    \def \meshthickness{0.01}
    \pgfmathsetmacro \maxposx {\dx*(\nx-1)/2}   
    \pgfmathsetmacro \maxposy {\dy*(\ny-1)/2}

    \draw[line width = 0.2mm] (0, \maxposy) -- (0, \maxposy + 0.8);

    \filldraw[black] circle (2pt) coordinate (-c); 

    \draw [dashed, line width = 0.2mm] (-\maxposx,\maxposy) -- (\maxposx,\maxposy);
    \draw [dashed, line width = 0.2mm] (\maxposx,\maxposy) -- (\maxposx,-\maxposy);
    \draw [dashed, line width = 0.2mm] (-\maxposx,-\maxposy) -- (\maxposx,-\maxposy);
    \draw [dashed, line width = 0.2mm] (-\maxposx,-\maxposy) -- (-\maxposx,\maxposy);
    \draw [dashed, line width = 0.2mm] (0,-\maxposy) -- (0,\maxposy);

    \foreach \i in {1,...,\nx}{
        \foreach \j in {1,...,\ny}{
            \pgfmathsetmacro \x {(\i - (\nx + 1)/2)*\dx}        
            \pgfmathsetmacro \y {(\j - (\ny + 1)/2)*\dy}
            \filldraw[#1, draw=black, line width = 0.2mm] (\x,\y) circle (#2) coordinate (-\i-\j);
        }
    }
}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\pic (a) {gridd={fill=blue!20!white}{3mm}};

\begin{scope}[rotate around z=20]
\pic (b) {gridd={fill=red!80!white}{3mm}};
\end{scope}


\pic ["$\theta$",angle radius=1cm,draw,-stealth] {angle={a-2-2--a-c--b-2-2}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is great. Although exactly what I wanted, I still don't follow how you managed to use nodes for this. Any suggestions on what I could read to understand this?

Comment: @Sid I don't quite follow, but I can add some more explanations to my answer. Will ping you when I've updated.

Comment: @Sid Updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

Another option with tikz-Euclide.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,backgrounds,fit,decorations.pathreplacing,chains,snakes,positioning}  
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,bm}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide} %%% ADDED
\tikzset{
pics/gridd/.style n args={2}{
code = {%
    \def \s{0.5}
    \def \nx{3}
    \def \ny{2}
    \def \dx{3}
    \def \dy{3}
    \def \meshthickness{0.01}
    \pgfmathsetmacro \maxposx {\dx*(\nx-1)/2}   
    \pgfmathsetmacro \maxposy {\dy*(\ny-1)/2}

    \draw[line width = 0.2mm] (0, \maxposy) -- (0, \maxposy + 0.8);

    \filldraw[black] circle (2pt); 

    \draw [dashed, line width = 0.2mm] (-\maxposx,\maxposy) -- (\maxposx,\maxposy);
    \draw [dashed, line width = 0.2mm] (\maxposx,\maxposy) -- (\maxposx,-\maxposy);
    \draw [dashed, line width = 0.2mm] (-\maxposx,-\maxposy) -- (\maxposx,-\maxposy);
    \draw [dashed, line width = 0.2mm] (-\maxposx,-\maxposy) -- (-\maxposx,\maxposy);
    \draw [dashed, line width = 0.2mm] (0,-\maxposy) -- (0,\maxposy);

    \foreach \i in {1,...,\nx}{
        \foreach \j in {1,...,\ny}{
            \pgfmathsetmacro \x {(\i - (\nx + 1)/2)*\dx}        
            \pgfmathsetmacro \y {(\j - (\ny + 1)/2)*\dy}
            \filldraw[#1, draw=black, line width = 0.2mm] (\x,\y) circle (#2);
        }
    }
}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoints{-0.8/2.1/A, 0/2.3/B}; %ADDED
\draw[stealth-stealth] (A) -- (B); % ADDED
\tkzLabelSegment[sloped](A,B) {$\theta$}; %ADDED
\pic {gridd={fill=blue!20!white}{3mm}};

\begin{scope}[rotate around z=20]
\pic {gridd={fill=red!80!white}{3mm}};
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Defining A en B relative to your dots, could make it work. 
[image]